# How to enhance reporting with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

This question is a little broad, so apologies in advance.

The company I work for recently switched to a new system which uses SQL Server instead of Mysql and our team is tasked with bringing several old reports over.  Because the new system models things a bit differently, we aren't aiming for 1-1 parity with old reports.

These are our current limitations:

- We can only provide SSRS reports - only what can fit in a `.rdl` file
- We can query the database and add views
- We are unable to add stored procedures and functions due to some licensing agreement
- We are also unable to add additional databases to the server

However, to my knowledge some of the reports will require:

- Building tables by looping over data an arbitrary number of times (e.g. walking a bill of material structure)
- some minor state tracking during evaluation, like running totals

I've tried to be clever and tackle the second requirement with a combination of CTEs and `ROW_NUMBER`, for example:

```
with t as 
(
    select 
        row_num = row_number() over (order by a), 
        a, b, c 
    from 
        table1
)
select
    a, 
    (select sum(b) from t t2 where t2.row_num < t.row_num) as running_b,
    (select sum(c) from t t3 where t3.row_num < t.row_num) as running_c
from 
    t
order by 
    row_num;
```

In this case `row_number` is required because `a` values could be identical.

However, SQL Server doesn't appear to do the math correctly for every row, or I have misunderstood something about the query. A co-worker has frequently complained about similar issues with the pivot function.

My question isn't about a single query though. We need to add more power to our queries within our current limitations, and I need some advice on how to do that.

Can anyone help?

### UPDATE

In reference to the example query, I found that SQL Server gave me the expected results if I swap the subselect with a left self-join along with a group clause:

```
with t as 
(
    select 
        row_num = row_number() over (order by a), 
        a, b, c 
    from 
        table1
)
select
    a, 
    sum(t2.b) as running_b,
    sum(t2.c) as running_c
from 
    t
    left join t t2 on t2.row_num < t.row_num
group by 
    t.row_num, t.a
order by 
    row_num;
```

Additionally, JacobH made me aware of Recursive CTEs, and I think that will help with the other issue.  I think these two techniques solve my most pressing concerns.

Comment: you might want to start with the schema the current data and the desired result.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu, It's a very large Macola database, and we are providing several reports daily, not just one.  With our old system, we could write stored procedures and functions, so we had all the power we needed.  The question is how to recapture that power since we can no longer do that.

Comment: okay. good luck.

Comment: "We are also unable to add additional databases to the server", ridiculous policy!! I think you try to have another SQL Server and link it to the reporting server you have. then you can write stored procedures. The only problem might be the performance.

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: Time to build a data warehouse if you can't add stored procedures to your server for reporting. Also, walking a BOM does not require a loop. Look into recursive CTEs. I've never had a problem with the PIVOT function, sounds like a PEBCAK error. And finally, if you are on a newer version of SQL server you can check out `LAG` and `LEAD` as they should help you out with the running total.

Comment: Try providing some basic sample data where the calculation goes wrong? It is not my impression that SQL Server in general does calculations wrong - usually it is a mistake in the query.

Comment: Jacob H, I'm not sure what version we're on but I'll try those suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: To find your version just execute `select @@VERSION`

Comment: we're running version 2016

Comment: @JacobH Trying to learn how to use recursive CTEs and LAG.  Got a pretty good handle on recursive CTEs but it looks like LAG won't allow me to do what I'd like.  https://pastebin.com/tkYb7NAq